how to display an element of an x-for in a div in alpinejs
For example, I want to dynamically show that clicking on any for element updates the display dynamically. How could this be achieved? In alpinejs
<div x-data="{products: [{title: 'test01', subtitle: 'lorem lorem lorem', tags: [{title: 'tag01'},{title: 'tag02'}]}, {title: 'test02', subtitle: 'lorem lorem lorem', tags: [{title: 'tag03'},{title: 'tag04'}]}], option: 0}">

<div class="view_dinamic_content">
<span class="view_title"></span>
<p class="view_description"></p>
<ul class="view_tags">
<li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>


<ul>
<template x-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">
     <li x-text="product.title" @click="option = index">
     </li>
</template>
</ul>

</div>

any explanation of this please

What do you want to display dynamically? Where do you want it to display?

How to dynamically send that when selecting an element in the x-for with @click, each data is displayed in the divs above

You should be able to use the option value as an index to access the products array. products[option] will give the selected item:


<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.13.10" integrity="sha384-XBJ5+bq4ga1+0s+J4sl6njqQ9C/YIfKeQw18HypSuGEaPm1g/VWaNdsQ5d3sE1qi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div x-data="{products: [{title: 'test01', subtitle: 'lorem lorem lorem', tags: [{title: 'tag01'},{title: 'tag02'}]}, {title: 'test02', subtitle: 'lorem lorem lorem', tags: [{title: 'tag03'},{title: 'tag04'}]}], option: 0}">
  <div class="view_dinamic_content">
    <span class="view_title" x-text="products[option].title"></span>
    <p class="view_description" x-text="products[option].subtitle"></p>
    <ul class="view_tags">
      <template x-for="tag in products[option].tags">
        <li x-text="tag.title"></li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <template x-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">
     <li x-text="product.title" @click="option = index">
     </li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</div>



